# htaccess redirect help please

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I previously asked this question and the answer did not seem to work as required - it also required an addition.

Users are provided with unique URL's, ie: exampleurl.com/`AQ4ILB9`
AQ4ILB9 being the referral code

1. I would like that URL above (or any referral URL) to display the contents of index.php (htaccess redirect?)
2. I would like the non-www and www version of exampleurl.com, including example.com/index.php to be redirected to the top level in this format: http://www.exampleurl.com/
3. I would like for example: `$_GET['_url']` to hold the referral id (ie: `AQ4ILB9`) in index.php

How can I go about the above 3 all using htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The first part is a 301 redirect to add www.

The second part will rewrite what you want, but not for existing files/directories.

Answer (score 1):

Q) 1 & 3:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,P]
```

Q) 2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampleurl.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exampleurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace example.com with your domain and put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?_url=$1 [L]
```

Should do the trick! You may not need the `RewriteEngine On` line if it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?_url=$1
```